# Measure of uniformity / homogeniy in an Image c++, opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I would like to use a metric which would be a good representation of the homogeneity / uniformity in a Gray - Scale image.

This is an example of a non uniform image:

[image]

This is an example of a uniform image:

[image]

any thoughts on what would be a good solution ??

EDIT: The images don't have a constant scale i.e. the width and the height of the image is varying. To add more context. I am using this on a project to differentiate between a bus and a truck from a side view pov. So the two images that I have added is a region between the two wheels for the truck and the bus. What I have observed is that the region will be uniform for a bus and non uniform for a truck. To define the region more precisely its width is equal to the distance between two wheels and height is equal to the height of the complete wheel. Why I am using this region: because I am receiving gray scale images of the buses and trucks. It is not necessary that the entire vehicle fits into the image i.e. it is quite possible that the top part of vehicle i.e. slightly above window might be not available to me that is why this approach.

Attached images here are in RGB whereas the images that I am receiving for a project are in Gray Scale. It is not necessary that I will receive images of the full vehicle. The below images are best possible scenario for me.

[image]
[image]

However these regions are not constant and depend on the size of the bus and truck. So I would like to measure the uniformity in those regions using a metric.

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask] questions.

Comment: Why not just check the standard deviation of the pixel values?

Comment: @PasserBy ... could you please tell me where should I improve ??

Comment: @AyushPandey more or less, Stack Overflow is not for asking for approaches but for solutions to problems. Asking how to approach a problem is considered off-topic, because it can resort to disagreements about methods.

Comment: thanks @AlexanderReynolds ... will keep that in mind before asking the next question .... also thanks for the answer .... will try computing the standard deviation by pixels

Comment: This is a fairly difficult question. All methods that rely on gray-level dispersion will essentially measure the noise/texture, not the uniformity. Maybe the question is more easily answered if you tell us the purpose of assessing uniformity.

Comment: Yeah, it really depends on the application here. For instance, the second picture is more or less a gradient. This means that although it's "smooth", it won't have a small standard deviation. A naïve metric you *could* apply if you wanted to test local homogeneity is to apply successive Gaussian blurs until the absolute/sum of square difference between the most recent blur and the one before is small.

Comment: I have added the context. If you could spare some time to go through it.

Comment: Mh, in terms of non-uniformity of the whole scene, I guess that there is no significant difference between the two images. They are much more similar than you think, by any method. You 'd better rely on the detection of windows, or any other clue related to the a priori shapes of those vehicles types...

Comment: The histograms of those two images would be very different at least, but locally, they're both very homogeneous---not clear whether that's a contrived example or if there will be much more difficult images in a set. Unless all the examples would be that basic and you always have an ROI between the wheels, I agree with @YvesDaoust that features (and lack thereof) would likely be more robust. Also kudos to Yves for immediately seeing through this [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds "The histograms of those two images would be very different at least": no. Both histograms are essentially identical, with a huge peak at white and a tiny one in the blacks. (Well, actually the bus has a double peak because the body is light gray; it could very well be the converse). It is absolutely impossible to tell a bus from a truck just from the histogram. And if you care to look at the histograms of the first two images, you cannot guess wich is the uniform one.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think you may have missed this when the OP added the bus/truck images: "So the two images that I have added is a region between the two wheels for the truck and the bus. "

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds: no, I didn't miss them. My previous comment speaks about the two pairs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One method (slightly naïve) that would test for local homogeneity across the image would be to repeatedly blur the image and sum the (absolute or square) differences between the most recent blur and the one before it. For example with your first two images, the repeated blurring would be changing the gradient-like image very little, whereas the change would be much larger in each succession for the first while with the first image. Consider this Python program:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

non = cv2.imread('img1.jpg', 0).astype(np.float32)/255
uni = cv2.imread('img2.jpg', 0).astype(np.float32)/255

blur_non = cv2.GaussianBlur(non, (11, 11), 2)
blur_uni = cv2.GaussianBlur(uni, (11, 11), 2)

for i in range(10):
    blur_non = cv2.GaussianBlur(blur_non, (11, 11), 2)
    blur_uni = cv2.GaussianBlur(blur_uni, (11, 11), 2)

last_blur_non = cv2.GaussianBlur(blur_non, (11, 11), 2)
last_blur_uni = cv2.GaussianBlur(blur_uni, (11, 11), 2)

ssd_blur_non = np.sum((last_blur_non - blur_non)**2)
ssd_blur_uni = np.sum((last_blur_uni - blur_uni)**2)

print('SSD Non-uniform: %f' % ssd_blur_non)
print('SSD Uniform:     %f' % ssd_blur_uni)
```

> SSD Non-uniform: 0.010601
>   SSD Uniform:     0.000321

So we can see here that sum of square differences between the last two blurs of the uniform image is 33 times smaller than that of the non-uniform image.

---

Another metric could be made by setting a threshold and seeing how many blurs it takes until the difference gets below it:

```
thresh = 1e-3

blur_count_non = 0
prev_blur_non = cv2.GaussianBlur(non, (11, 11), 2)
blur_non = cv2.GaussianBlur(blur_non, (11, 11), 2)
ssd_blur_non = np.sum((blur_non - prev_blur_non)**2)
while(ssd_blur_non > thresh):
    blur_non = cv2.GaussianBlur(prev_blur_non, (11, 11), 2)
    ssd_blur_non = np.sum((blur_non - prev_blur_non)**2)
    prev_blur_non = blur_non
    blur_count_non += 1

blur_count_uni = 0
prev_blur_uni = cv2.GaussianBlur(uni, (11, 11), 2)
blur_uni = cv2.GaussianBlur(blur_uni, (11, 11), 2)
ssd_blur_uni = np.sum((blur_uni - prev_blur_uni)**2)
while(ssd_blur_uni > thresh):
    blur_uni = cv2.GaussianBlur(prev_blur_uni, (11, 11), 2)
    ssd_blur_uni = np.sum((blur_uni - prev_blur_uni)**2)
    prev_blur_uni = blur_uni
    blur_count_uni += 1

print('Non-uniform blur count: %d' % blur_count_non)
print('Uniform blur count:     %d' % blur_count_uni)
```

> Non-uniform blur count: 79
>   Uniform blur count:     5

You can read these values like "number of blurs until homogeneity." If you make the threshold even smaller, say 0.01, then in fact a single run of the `while` loop (i.e. two blurs) gets the image you've said is mostly homogeneous under the threshold. In this example, the ratio between the two is about 16.

---

If you plot the SSD for each successive blur from the above approaches you'll see something like this:

[image: Successive blurs]

It's quite clear here that one of these lines sits on top of the other. Of course, the less-uniform image has a higher summed difference between each blur and it should more or less stay on top, especially in the beginning. The first method is akin to drawing a vertical line at some number of iterations and taking the min at that location would correspond to the more homogenous image. The second method is akin to drawing a horizontal line and saying "whichever line hits this first is the homogeneous one." Different direction, similar idea. Yet *another* idea along the same line: you could check the difference between the *change* in SSD. This is as simple as "whenever the slope becomes mostly horizontal between two points, the image is homogenous." And that of course happens very early in the number of iterations.

---

Another popular method with blurring is to take the difference of two different blurs; aka Difference of Gaussians as [Kamil mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46445408/5087436). This method is used sometimes to find edges in images; if there's a big difference between two blurs, it's because there's some differing responses to the blur at some point in the image, like an edge. But if they more or less blur similarly, then the image is quite smooth.

```
blur1_non = cv2.GaussianBlur(non, (7, 7), 1)
blur2_non = cv2.GaussianBlur(non, (31, 31), 2)
ssd_blur_non = np.sum((blur1_non - blur2_non)**2)

blur1_uni = cv2.GaussianBlur(uni, (7, 7), 1)
blur2_uni = cv2.GaussianBlur(uni, (31, 31), 2)
ssd_blur_uni = np.sum((blur1_uni - blur2_uni)**2)

print('SSD Non-uniform DoG: %f' % ssd_blur_non)
print('SSD Uniform DoG:     %f' % ssd_blur_uni)
```

> SSD Non-uniform DoG: 0.416841
>   SSD Uniform DoG:     0.026028

And here the ratio is around 20.

---

So all of these methods produce at least an order of magnitude difference between them, which should be easily detectable. But the difficulty can lie in what parameters to choose, what the standard deviation of the Gaussian should be, the size of the window, etc. You *can* try to base them off the size, e.g. taking Gaussian windows which are a fraction of the image size.

**NOTE**: Here I didn't bother scaling for the image size; you should divide all of the sums by the number of pixels in the image (i.e. taking an average) to get it to be scale invariant.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest computing 2D FFT (Fast fourier transform).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform

It would change our image intensity domain to frequency domain. If you  calculate magnitudes of transformation result it will produce an image like this (below image and result example):
[image: FFT results].

Below i attached two images - less uniform on left and more uniform on right side. You can see difference in frequency domain below:

[image]

You can compute signal to noise ratio with signal situated near center of an image (as a percentage of image size). That ratio could be easilly used as a metric.
FFT approach is well described here: https://books.google.pl/books?id=97QebyNxyaYC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=2dFFT+extract+mean+value&source=bl&ots=wV8kc-TrI-&sig=N35TiT3aI5HCYjop6_ORxCpBPMk&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikzP7VkMXWAhWCA5oKHfKEDVcQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=2dFFT%20extract%20mean%20value&f=false

Another feature extraction: http://cns-classes.bu.edu/cn550/Lectures/Lecture13.pdf

Similar results could be achieved by calculating DoG image (difference of gaussians) with large window, and then use mean image value as a metric (the less value the more uniform image is).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Indeed this is a good approach, but it would be best if you could expand a bit on your answer so that others without specialist knowledge could understand why magnitudes of Fourier coefficients would give such a metric. Not everyone coming to this site will know what a Fourier transform is/does :).

Comment: The two vehicle images have very similar DFT.

Comment: As i understood, there is some ROI located between wheels and its uniformity is used in order to recognize vehicle.

Comment: What's the relevance of comparing the spectra of a blurred and a sharp image ? The question is about uniform vs. non-uniform.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Uniform image is "the most blurred" image possible - it has onlya few levels of intensity

Comment: @KamilSzelag: ok, there is nothing I can do against bad faith.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

- compute the average value of all pixels
- then sum up the differences of the real pixels values with the computed average

?

The more diversity is in the image, the higher the computed value would be - this should give a rough estimate of the homogeneity / uniformity of the image.

Comment: Sorry for the late edit, I want a metric which would be independent of the Scale.

Comment: Should probably also divide by the number of pixels. @AyushPandey that would solve scaling. Also, you'd need to take the absolute sum or square differences, otherwise you could cancel out (e.g. if the image was 50% white, 50% black).

Comment: Any method that is based on the histogram of pixel values alone, such as your suggestion, is inappropriate. Because you can take any image and redistribute the pixels in scanline order by increasing gray-level. This will leave the histogram perfectly unchanged, but the image will appear like a perfectly smooth gradient.

Comment: I have added the context. If you could spare some time to go through it.